# Explanation of the algorithm to find a number 'm' made up of digits 0's and 1's which is divisible by the number n

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here's a piece of code from a udemy course that I am currently taking that uses the **pigeon hole** principle to find a number made up of 0's and 1's divisible by the number n.

```
void findNumber(int n) {
int cur_rem = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    cur_rem = (cur_rem * 10 + 1) % n;
    if(cur_rem == 0) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            cout << 1;
        return;
    }
    if(fr[cur_rem] != 0) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i - fr[cur_rem]; j++)
            cout << 1;
        for(int j = 1; j <= fr[cur_rem]; j++)
            cout << 0;
        return;
    }
    fr[cur_rem] = i;
}
```

}
So, in this code we actually first take the numbers 1,11,111,...,111..1(n times) and see if they are divisible by the given integer n. If they are not divisible then we find the 2 numbers within 1,11,111,...111..1(n times) with the same remainder when divided by the number n and subtract them to get the number that is divisible by n. So, I understand the theory part but I did not understand one line of the code.

Can someone please explain to me this line of code: `cur_rem = (cur_rem * 10 + 1) % n;` how can we get the remainder of the current number by multiplying the remainder of the previous number by 10 and then adding 1 and then finding the mod by dividing the sum by the given integer n?

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: What is `fr`? That's not shown here.

Comment: To understand that line of code, you need to understand that `(a*b) % n` is the same as `(a%n * b%n) % n`, and `(a+b) % n` is the same as `(a%n + b%n) % n`. One way to think about it is that you're doing math base-n, and you only care about the last digit.

Comment: @tadman fr is the frequency array in which the index number of the array denotes the remainder and the value stored in it is the length of the digit made up of only the number 1.

Comment: The reason I ask is it's not specified in your code. Try and keep your examples as *minimal* and *complete* as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the last number 111... (we'll call it m), had remainder r.

```
m % n = r
m = kn + r
```

Now the next number, 111..., call it m', is one digit longer than m.

```
m' = 10 m + 1
m' % n = (10 m        + 1) % n
       = (10(kn + r)  + 1) % n
       = (10 kn + 10r + 1) % n
       = (        10r + 1) % n
```

Comment: `m'` isn't a great C++ variable name.

Comment: @tadman: It isn't a great ice cream flavor either, so what? That isn't C++ code.